# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to resolve BasicAuthentication was not authenticated. Failure message: No contains header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API project, I am implementing Basic Authentication. I have this code:

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    public bool isUser(string username, string password);
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;        
    public UserService(
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public bool isUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var userFind = _dbContext.User.Where(u => u.Username == username && u.Password == password);
        if (userFind.Any()) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Then I have this Basic Auth Handler code in the helpers.

BasicAuthHandler:

```
public class BasicAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private readonly IUserService _repository;
    public BasicAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
                            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                            UrlEncoder urlEncoder,
                            ISystemClock systemClockm,
                            IUserService repository)
        : base(options, loggerFactory, urlEncoder, systemClockm)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization")) 
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No contains header");

        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            var AuthHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
            var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(AuthHeader.Parameter);
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);
            //get parameters in array format
            var username = credentials[0];
            var password = credentials[1];
            result = _repository.isUser(username, password);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Some ERROR");
        }
        if (!result)
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Error User Name or Password ");

        var claims = new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id"),
             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user")
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);
```

When I run the application, the page was blank, and I got this error in the log file:

> BasicAuthentication was not authenticated. Failure message: No contains header

Which indicates that it stops here:

```
if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization")) 
    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No contains header");

bool result = false;
```

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that the header is included in the request (on the client side)?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - Can you explain?  The error occurs as soon as I load the application

Comment: What is there to explain? I don't follow. If the client doesn't send an Authorization header then the header won't exist on the server...

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - What I was saying is that it has not even loaded at all, to allow the header to be passed

Comment: How does that relate to the code above then?

Comment: Perhaps you want to add `Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");` above the `if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))` line so that the browser's native login dialog will show for the site? Otherwise it sounds like you're not allowing anonymous access to the login page (if that's what you have).

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - The error still remains there

Comment: It seems pretty evident that you're not sending the Authorization header with your requests. Without more information about what you're doing and the behaviour you expect, it seems like you're expecting magic (i.e. you expect that you don't need to send an Authorization header and it will all just magically happen).

Comment: Your previous comment of _"What I was saying is that it has not even loaded at all, to allow the header to be passed"_ is also a little perplexing. To load a page you make a request for its HTML, which can include an Authorization header. Unless you're making AJAX requests using Javascript in the page, the page being loaded won't cause requests to be made (beyond loading resources like CSS, Images, Javascript, etc.) so I don't know why you would expect headers to be added at this point, or to where.

Comment: Browsers work like this:  Attempt to load a page.  If the server responds with HTTP 401 UNAUTHORIZED, the browser will attempt to authenticate based on the server response's header `WWW-Authenticate` contents.  If `WWW-Authenticate` is `Basic` then the browser will ask the user for username and password.  So you must make sure that you always respond with 401 UNAUTHORIZED and the `WWW-Authenticate` header to obtain the desired result.

Comment: if it a webapi nothing happens unless you call an API. how are you calling API, postman, swaggerui or directly from browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
{
    Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = "Basic";
    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No contains header");
}
```

It will pop up the login window on browser like below

[image]

and once you give correct credentials , it will authenticate and return the result

[image]

Comment: Still not working

Comment: what is not working. are still getting same error or your method is still not being hit.? i tried your complete code + some changes to hook up to rest of the middleware. would be helpful to put some screenshot. i hope you have added all the required middlewares.

Comment: Might also need to add `Response.StatusCode = 401;`

Comment: @CodingMytra - The login for username and password keep on coming several times

Comment: @CodingMytra - Which middleware am I to add again. I am getting Error: Response status is 401.   Yes I successfully added the username and password

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I would think `AuthenticateResult.Fail` would return a 401 already.

Comment: @Ayobamilaye , if you are getting the login popup then it means it is working. now you should check the next step where you are trying to validate the username and password in your `public bool isUser(string username, string password)` method.

Comment: @CodingMytra - Each time I enter username and password it pops up again

Comment: you are comparing username and password in plain text. are you storing your password in plain text in database ?